# Mysql query to search number of lead with status VALID by user

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql table of historic and lead status

table 1 lead  :

id,user,status,date

table 2 historic_lead:

id,lead_id,status

how tow search number of lead with status VALID by user today where  in historic_lead.status don't have status not_valid

ex table 1 :
1,user_1,valid,2019-25-06

ex table 2 :
452,1,not_valid
453,1,valid

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. However, if you show is what you have tried and continue to have issues, we can perhaps help you figure things out

Comment: Little hint with what SQL clauses/functions you can combine to get your answer try it first atleast. the SQL clauses/functions are `LEFT JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, `WHERE`, `AND`, `NOW()`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

your foreign key exist on historic_lead table. so start from that and join lead table.
look below query

```
  "SELECT * FROM historic_lead LEFT JOIN lead ON lead.id=historic_lead.lead_id WHERE lead.status='valid' AND historic_lead.status!='not_valid';
```

Comment: you need to add more explenation to you answer

Comment: SELECT yj_fiche.nom_confirmateur , COUNT(*) FROM yj_histo_fiche LEFT JOIN yj_fiche ON yj_fiche.id=yj_histo_fiche.id_fiche WHERE yj_fiche.etat_final='CONFIRMER' AND yj_histo_fiche.etat!='ANNLER ET A REPROGRAMMER' AND DATE(yj_fiche.date_heure_mod)=CURRENT_DATE() 
GROUP BY   yj_fiche.nom_confirmateur

I USE THIS BUT THE COUNT IS NOT CORRECT

Comment: Dont use count inside query. get rows count after executing the query.